# Installing OBOE on Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: package-management

I [am mostly following this post to install OBOE](https://projects.coin-or.org/OBOE/wiki/MacosxOboe) on MAC OS X 10.9.

However, following step 4, I tried to install LAPACK++ with failure [from this source](http://switch.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/lapackpp/lapackpp-2.5.2.tar.gz):

I type `./configure`

```
configure: error: Blas/Lapack was not found.
*** This means Lapack++ and matrix support cannot be compiled.
*** This makes this library unusable. Please get blas and lapack
*** installed. If you do have these installed, use the options
*** --with-blas=<libname> or --with-lapack=<libname> and/or set
*** the env variable LDFLAGS to include the appropriate linker
*** flags.
```

But I have `libblas.a`, `liblapack.a`, `librefblas.a`, `libtmglib.a` in my `/usr/local/lin` folder.  Can any one help?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have BLAS installed first? According to [these detailed, step-by-step instructions](http://pheiter.wordpress.com/2012/09/04/howto-installing-lapack-and-blas-on-mac-os/):

> First, you have to install BLAS, because LAPACK requires it.

More instructions on installing [LAPACK++ on Mac OS X can be found here](http://ice-huli.blogspot.com/2010/04/lapackpp-253-on-mac-os-x-1063.html).

Comment: yea, I install BLAS first then installed LAPACK